# Hostname case difference for Linux and Win32 cmd prompt and C

Tags: c, command-line, hostname

I am using the hostname while creating an App and then using the hostname in its Friendly Name. I am providing this hostname as an agrument while creating the App.

Then this App is further used by other Apps/Processes.
This whole code is being used on both Linux and Win32. 
Now, the problem is that `%COMPUTERNAME%` in Win32 returns all caps, regardless of whether the actual hostname is all caps or not. 
But on Linux `${MYHOSTNAME}` returns, as is with respective case.

So the issue is that my code fails for Win32 as `%COMPUTERNAME%` returns `SUNNY890`
but the actual code (written in c) (`gethostname(strHost,sizeof(strHost)`) returns `sunny890`.

Is there a way to fix this issue?
Thanks and regards, 
Sunny

Comment: You can check if you are currently under windows or linux http://stackoverflow.com/a/3213261/612920

Comment: Stick to the capitalized version on both systems. Or use a non case-sensitive version of `strcmp()`: `strcasecmp()`

Comment: @alk: how to i do that for Linux? ${MYHOSTNAME} returns "sunny890"

Comment: You might use `toupper()` to convert a character to it's uppercase version.